# Get Class from External Library's Binary

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Is it possible to get a class from an external library's binary in ObjC?

Like i kno the name of the class, and im just tryna test a view to see if its a type of class

ive tried forward declarations, but that didnt work

for instance:

```
if([subview isKindOfClass:[ExternalBinaryView class]])
    {
        ExternalBinaryView* _foo = subview;
    }
```

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the header files aren't supplied use [NSClassFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html).

```
if([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"ExternalBinaryView")])
{
    ExternalBinaryView* _foo = subview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the header file for that class:

```
#import <LibraryName/ExternalBinaryView.h>
```

Or if there's a common header to import everything:

```
#import <LibraryName/LibraryName.h>
```

Your code should then work as expected.

Comment: but the header files arent supplied